# IIS7 Virtual Directory gives 403 Forbidden Access Denied

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory

I have some issues with IIS7 setup that I hope someone can help me with.

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC5 application which consist of 1 web application and 1 web api application for handling REST calls. They are on the same solution in Visual Studio. While developing, they run on the localhost with two different ports as usual.

Now that I am deploying to a web server, I planned to have them running like this:

Web app: http://mydomain.com
Web api: http://mydomain.com/api

So I created a site on IIS for the web app and virtual directory under that site with an alias of "api".

The web application runs without issue and I can put a static test HTML file under api folder and it runs fine. But when I put all my published file in api folder, I got 403 Forbidden Access Denied.

My questions: can I run an ASP.NET application on a Virtual Folder? If so, what I might have done wrong? The folder permissions are the same between ./mydomain.com and ./mydomain.com/api folders.

Comment: Do you have directory browser disabled in IIS? If this is the case, and you also do not have the file extension you are using for your published file under your API folder set as a default document under this site directory then you should get a 403 access denied i believe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. The site itself works. Would it be possible Virtual Directory under it has different setting on the directory browser disabled/enabled? Anyway, how do I check it? Cheers.

Comment: It appears as though i was incorrect. Instead of getting the 403 error you are getting when these settings are BOTH set wrong on your site you would be receiving a 404 error from the server.

Comment: If i were you i would enable directory browser on the virtual directory. Then see if you can access your API inside of it.